# moc not found during mame emulator compile on gentoo

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, emulation, gentoo

i'm a new be here. 
I'm trying to install the Mame emulator on gentoo using this ebuild https://github.com/PaddyMac/overlay/tree/master/games-emulation/mame
A problem appear during compilation as you can see in the log below it seems that moc compiler is missing.
I did

`emerge moc`

to solve it but still the same issue

```
[31;01m*[0m Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/games-emulation/mame-0.148/work'
 [31;01m*[0m S: '/var/tmp/portage/games-emulation/mame-0.148/work'
 Compiling source in /var/tmp/portage/games-emulation/mame-0.148/work ...
 [32;01m*[0m Grab a cup of coffee or a beer. This will take a while.
 make all TARGET=mame BUILD_EXPAT=0 BUILD_FLAC=0 BUILD_JPEGLIB=0 BUILD_MIDILIB=0  BUILD_ZLIB=0 NOWERROR=1 NO_X11=0 DEBUG=0 NO_DEBUGGER=1 NO_OPENGL=0 PROFILER=0 USE_QTDEBUG=0 NO_USE_XINPUT=1 
src/osd/sdl/sdl.mak:491: *** Qt's Meta Object Compiler (moc) wasn't found!.  Stop.
 [31;01m*[0m ERROR: games-emulation/mame-0.148::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 [31;01m*[0m   emake failed
 [31;01m*[0m 
 [31;01m*[0m If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=games-emulation/mame-0.148::gentoo'`,
 [31;01m*[0m the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=games-emulation/mame-0.148::gentoo'`.
 [31;01m*[0m The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/games-emulation/mame-0.148/temp/build.log'.
 [31;01m*[0m The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/games-emulation/mame-0.148/temp/environment'.
 [31;01m*[0m Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/games-emulation/mame-0.148/work'
 [31;01m*[0m S: '/var/tmp/portage/games-emulation/mame-0.148/work'
```

Thank you guys

Comment: I suggest to report it there : https://github.com/PaddyMac/overlay/issues

Answer (score 0):

Moc is provided by dev-qt/qtcore, try installing that if it is not already on the system and see if the problem goes away.  Regardless, do as @Heather suggested and file a bug with the ebuild maintainer.